# ID3 Reader tags to retrieve Artist name, song, and album art using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, functional-programming

I'm current trying to use ID3 tag JavaScript library to retrieve MP3 file information from a URL link. I'm looking for artist name, song name and album art.

My problem is I can retrieve some data using a url but i have my url's in an array how can i update the url once the song has finished? In addition the code im about to show is buggy as it doesnt allow my default audio player to work either.

```
/**
 * Loading the tags using XHR.
 */
//sample.mp3 sits on your domain
ID3.loadTags("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hugnrhqxc04vbtb/3%20-%20Penicillin_281214300_soundcloud.mp3", function() {
  showTags("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hugnrhqxc04vbtb/3%20-%20Penicillin_281214300_soundcloud.mp3");
}, {
  tags: ["title","artist","album","picture"]
});

/**
 * Loading the tags using the FileAPI.
 */
function loadFile(input) {
  var file = input.files[0],
    url = file.urn || file.name;

  ID3.loadTags(url, function() {
    showTags(url);
  }, {
    tags: ["title","artist","album","picture"],
    dataReader: ID3.FileAPIReader(file)
  });
}

/**
 * Generic function to get the tags after they have been loaded.
 */
function showTags(url) {
  var tags = ID3.getAllTags(url);
  console.log(tags);
  document.getElementById('title').textContent = tags.title || "";
  document.getElementById('artist').textContent = tags.artist || "";
  document.getElementById('album').textContent = tags.album || "";
  var image = tags.picture;
  if (image) {
    var base64String = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i++) {
        base64String += String.fromCharCode(image.data[i]);
    }
    var base64 = "data:" + image.format + ";base64," +
            window.btoa(base64String);
    document.getElementById('picture').setAttribute('src',base64);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('picture').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

My acceptance criteria is as follows:

- URL will display artist name, song name, album art.
- URL will be updated upon a new song and then display its update information.